# DistributionWarning: discord.py is installed which is incompatible with nextcord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, nextcord

How to fix this? When I run my discord bot, this appeared in terminal

```
DistributionWarning: discord.py is installed which is incompatible with nextcord. Please remove this library by using pip3 uninstall discord.py

  warn(message, DistributionWarning, stacklevel=0)
```

Comment: `Please remove this library by using pip3 uninstall discord.py` says what you have to do. Where is the problem? What program are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In order for nextcord to work you need discord.py uninstalled.

So do this in your terminal:

```
pip3 uninstall discord.py
```

If you have discord.py[voice]:

```
pip uninstall discord.py[voice]
```

Then you install nextcord

```
pip3 install nextcord
```

Voice:

```
pip3 install nextcord[voice]
```